# Android Video Game Using 2D Array - Find connecting matches

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array

Okay, I am building a game in my free time for fun. This is not for work or school. I graduated. What I didn't do is graduate in game programming so I am learning it as I go. I have developed a couple of games, but this one is probably my most advanced.

I have about 5 2d arrays. One to hold the Bitmaps, one to hold X locations, one to hold Y locations, one to hold the state of the element (they are birds, status is for flying state and hit state), and one identifying what the element is. Each array works together to give me a game board with birds flapping their wings. I can touch the game board, I get the location back. This part all works.

What I am trying to do is create a way to detect if elements nearby are the same element as the flagged element (the touched item). When this happens I basically want to flag all of these elements as "Hit". This is not just getting the 8 blocks around the element, this is getting every item touching the flagged item and identifying them as "Hit". You probably have played games like this, maybe. They are puzzle like games (mines cooler because the birds poop on you and it kills your character :) ). I created another 2D array to tack hit state (in this latest iteration of my attempt to solve the problem, so I don't double count a hit, and I am now using it to flag items I don't count with a -1.

My arrays are all [8][8] arrays. They don't change, they will always be that way. This should make it easier. So as an example:

[sample from game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqk8p.png)

The circled red birds in the image should have been flagged as hit as well.

On to the code:

```
 public void calculateGunDestruction(){
    int currentRow = targetBirdRow;
    int currentCol = targetBirdCol;
    int hitbird = whichBird[targetBirdRow][targetBirdCol];
    boolean[] pathState = new boolean[5];
    countedArray = new int[8][8];
    for(int j = 0; j < countedArray.length;j++){
        for(int jj = 0; jj< countedArray[j].length;jj++){
            countedArray[j][jj] = 0;
        }
    }
    for(int i = currentRow;i < whichBird.length; i++) {
        for (int ii = currentCol; ii < whichBird[i].length; ii++) {
            pathState = pathMatch(i,ii,hitbird);
            if(!pathState[0] && !pathState[1] && !pathState[2] && !pathState[3]){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!pathState[0] && !pathState[1] && !pathState[2] && !pathState[3]){
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = currentRow;i > -1; i--) {
        for (int ii = currentCol; ii < whichBird[i].length; ii++) {
            pathState = pathMatch(i,ii,hitbird);
            if(!pathState[0] && !pathState[1] && !pathState[2] && !pathState[3]){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!pathState[0] && !pathState[1] && !pathState[2] && !pathState[3]){
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = currentRow;i < whichBird.length; i++) {
        for (int ii = currentCol; ii > - 1; ii--) {
            pathState = pathMatch(i,ii,hitbird);
            if(!pathState[0] && !pathState[1] && !pathState[2] && !pathState[3]){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!pathState[0] && !pathState[1] && !pathState[2] && !pathState[3]){
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = currentRow;i > -1; i--) {
        for (int ii = currentCol; ii > - 1; ii--) {
            pathState = pathMatch(i,ii,hitbird);
            if(!pathState[0] && !pathState[1] && !pathState[2] && !pathState[3]){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!pathState[0] && !pathState[1] && !pathState[2] && !pathState[3]){
            break;
        }
    }
}


 public boolean[] pathMatch(int i, int ii, int hitbird){

    boolean pathTop = false;
    boolean pathBottom = false;
    boolean pathLeft = false;
    boolean pathRight = false;

    if(findMatch(i,ii,hitbird)) {
        if(countedArray[i][ii] == 0) {
            countedArray[i][ii] = 1;
            destroyedBirds(i, ii);
        }
        if((i - 1) > -1) {
            if (countedArray[i - 1][ii] == 0) {
                if (findMatch(i - 1, ii, hitbird)) {
                    countedArray[i - 1][ii] = 1;
                    destroyedBirds(i - 1, ii);
                    pathLeft = true;
                } else {countedArray[i - 1][ii] = -1;pathLeft = false;}
            } else {pathLeft = false;}
        } else {pathLeft = false;}
        if((i + 1) < 8) {
            if (countedArray[i + 1][ii] == 0) {
                if (findMatch(i + 1, ii, hitbird)) {
                    countedArray[i + 1][ii] = 1;
                    destroyedBirds(i + 1, ii);
                    pathRight = true;
                } else {countedArray[i + 1][ii] = -1;pathRight = false;}
            } else {pathRight = false;}
        }else {pathRight = false;}
        if((ii - 1) > -1) {
            if (countedArray[i][ii - 1] == 0) {
                if (findMatch(i, ii - 1, hitbird)) {
                    countedArray[i][ii - 1] = 1;
                    destroyedBirds(i, ii - 1);
                    pathTop = true;
                } else {countedArray[i][ii - 1] = -1;pathTop = false;}
            } else {pathTop = false;}
        } else {pathTop = false;}
        if((ii + 1) < 8) {
            if (countedArray[i][ii + 1] == 0) {
                if (findMatch(i, ii + 1, hitbird)) {
                    countedArray[i][ii + 1] = 1;
                    destroyedBirds(i, ii + 1);
                    pathBottom = true;
                } else {countedArray[i][ii + 1] = -1;pathBottom = false;}
            } else {pathBottom = false;}
        }else {pathBottom = false;}
    }else{
        countedArray[i][ii] = -1;
    }

    return new boolean[]{pathTop,pathBottom,pathLeft,pathRight};
}

public boolean findMatch(int row,int col,int hitbird){
    if(hitbird == whichBird[row][col]){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public void destroyedBirds(int row,int col){
    destroyedBirdsRow.add(0, row);
    destroyedBirdsCol.add(0, col);
}
```

I have tried several different ways, this is just the latest as of this writing. Some were closer than others, but none quite got it. These seems like it should be a real simple thing to do, but I am not a game programmer professionally, game programming is something I am trying to learn.

The code above basically breaks the 2D array out into quadrants from the point at which you touch. I added the control "countedArray" with this attempt because I knew there was no real way to stop double counting with this method without some sort of way to track it. It goes left/down, left,up, right/down, right/up from the touch point. 
the touch points near the top:

```
int currentRow = targetBirdRow;
int currentCol = targetBirdCol;
int hitbird = whichBird[targetBirdRow][targetBirdCol];
```

hit bird holds the identifier of the touched bird or element. This is not a terribly elegant solution, but it also doesn't work. At this point elegance is thrown out the window, I am about to write a long nasty looking piece of code that no one can read checking each item individual with no looping and hope that works. So cobbled solutions are okay.

For reference sake - the area the above code is called from looks like this:

```
if(playerObj.getWeaponSelected() == wGun) {
    calculateGunDestruction();//CALLING FUNCTION

    for (int i = 0; i < destroyedBirdsRow.size(); i++) {
        state[destroyedBirdsRow.get(i)][destroyedBirdsCol.get(i)] = hit;
    }
    destroyedBirdsRow.clear();
    destroyedBirdsCol.clear();
```

[Full Game Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a4rX.jpg)
I have edited to add a full game image. Questions on why it is over complicated prompted me to explain a bit. (And yes, there may be better ways to do it - I am certainly no expert on this). The idea is, as the birds are hit, to display a brief hit image, make the hit bird disappear, and then move birds in from the left, adding a new bird(s) to replace the hit birds. That structure all works - if not perhaps over complicated in design. Single hits work, bomb hits work (when you shoot a bomb that randomly appears on the board as a new bird). I use the position arrays to guide the animation of the birds that need to move in to fill the gap left by the hit birds. I wouldn't be surprised to learn of a better way, and I am here and doing this to learn so feel free to comment outside of the original scope of the question. It may help others trying to learn, and me; and I think that really is the most important point of a site like this.

As far as the part I am having difficulty getting to work. When I shoot the gun, the idea was to have it peg all birds of the same color/species that are touching the hit bird, mark them as hit, and make them disappear. And yes, the code I currently have for that section is probably the most complicated version I wrote. I started over at least a dozen times now. The simplest version involved two groups of loops and less outside methods (it was half the size) - it worked about as well as this one, but tended to flag extra birds. This one doesn't seem to flag extra birds, but doesn't get them all.

I have built a few small games in the past - but this one is by far the most complex one I have attempted and its looking pretty good so far - except for the whole grouped kill thing.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your downfall with this is over complication in design. I am struggling to understand why you need 5 8x8 arrays to store a 2D game board.

Your solution for marking hit tiles and those around it should be something like this for simplicity:

```
public static final int NOTHING=0,BIRD_FLYING=1,BIRD_HIT=2,
                        TILE_LAND=0,TILE_WATER=1;

private int[][] gameBoard=new int[8][8]; // Store terrain etc.
private int[][] birds=new int[8][8]; // Store entities on the map
private int tileSize=32; // Store the size of the tile in pixels
private Image landImg,seaImg,flyingImg,hitImg; // Store the tile images (or use 1 tilesheet and segment it in the draw method)

private void hitTile(int x,int y)
{
    for(int i=-1;i<=1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=-1;j<=1;j++)
        {
            birds[hitX+i,hitY+j]=BIRD_HIT;
        }
    }
}

private void drawTheTiles()
{
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            // Draw background tiles first
            switch(gameBoard[i][j])
            {
                default:
                case TILE_LAND:
                    g.drawImage(landImg,i*tileSize,j*tileSize,this);
                    break;
                case TILE_SEA:
                    g.drawImage(seaImg,i*tileSize,j*tileSize,this);
                    break;
            }
            // Draw entities on tiles last
            switch(gameBoard[i][j])
            {
                default:
                case NOTHING:
                    // Don't draw anything
                    break;
                case BIRD_FLYING:
                    g.drawImage(flyingImg,i*tileSize,j*tileSize,this);
                    break;
                case BIRD_HIT:
                    g.drawImage(hitImg,i*tileSize,j*tileSize,this);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll need to add in your own handling, image loading, rendering, and array entries but there should be no need to store positions in an array for a 2D game board like this, as the positions can be implied by the tile index.

I hope this gives you *something* to go on. But I'm afraid I don't fully understand your original program/premise.

Comment: The only reason I chose that many arrays (yes it maybe over complicated) is that the 8X8 board is not the entire game board. X and Y positions are stored to begin placement on the game board, and then when hit, they stay marked as hit briefly, then the hit bird or birds, disappear, and new birds fly in from the left - instituting a change in the X Y positions. So having them in the array form, I can run it into a loop so show the change animation easier. (or at least the easiest way I could think of). Below the 8X8 board is a player, she shoots at the birds. She loses health when pooped on.

Comment: I think I may change my original idea. I have single hits working. I can do the bomb hits (get rid of all birds of a single color) but this group hit thing would take someone much smarter than I. I just hate to give up on something because its too hard, and the fact that its too hard is driving me more to figure out a solution.